# Associative Array with Vector in C++

Tags: vector, maps, associative-array

I need to implement my map with a vector. My map is layed out like:

```
map<strong,double> mapName;
```

I need to convert over to vector so that I can do a linear search through the elements.

Thanks in advance for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily convert to a vector using vector's range constructor like so:

```
 map<string,double> item_map;
 // ... populate item map ...

 // copy elements to a vector.
 vector< pair<string,double> > item_vector(item_map.begin(), item_map.end());
```

However, if you only need to do a linear search, you don't need to copy the elements.  Just iterator over the items like so:

```
 typedef map<string,double>::iterator iterator;
 iterator current = item_map.begin();
 const iterator end = item_map.end();
 for (; current != end; ++current) {
     // current->first is the 'string' part.
     // current->second is the 'double' part.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert to vector to do a linear search. You can use C++ iterators to grab the beginning of a map and the end, then access the key and value with first and second.

[See this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)

For example:

```
for (map<strong, double>::iterator ii = mapName.begin(); 
    ii!=mapName.end();ii++) {
      cout << ii->first << endl;  //returns a key
      cou << ii->second << endl; //returns ii->first's current corresponding value.
}
```