# C++ vector of strings into associative vector of ints

Tags: c++, unordered-multiset

Im having trouble to convert a string vector with size of ~ 1.0000.0000 elements to an associative vector with integers.

Input:

```
std::vector<std::string> s {"a","b","a","a","c","d","a"};
```

Desired output:

```
std::vector<int> i {0,1,0,0,2,3,0};
```

I was thinking of an `std::unordered_multiset` as mentioned in [Associative Array with Vector in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368794/associative-array-with-vector-in-c) but i can't get it running.

The goal is to reduce the time it takes to convert c++ strings to R strings, which is so much faster if I just use numbers.

Thank you for your help!

Edit:

Thats how I tried to populate the set:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
{
        set.insert(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: What did you try doing with `unordered_multiset`? What specific problem did you have with it?

Comment: If i populate the set like done in the edit, i do just receive the first element if iterate through the set with ```ii->data()``` thus, i "don't need" the values, but the keys i think

Comment: We need more code :) what's `set`? and `ii`? where's the map? Please add this to the question instead of comments!

Comment: Does the input need to be ordered? Why not use std::transform? Why do you need a std::unordered_multiset for?
A simple code like this could do the trick
std::vector<std::string> in{"a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d", "a"};
std::vector<int> out(in.size());
std::transform(in.cbegin(), in.cend(), out.begin(), [] (const std::string &s) {
  return s[0] - 'a';
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will output your desired output for your given input. And it will process 1.000.000 strings of length 3 in 0.4s. So I think unordered_map is a viable choice.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

// generator function for creating a large number of strings.
std::vector<std::string> generate_strings(const std::size_t size, const std::size_t string_length)
{
    static std::random_device rd{};
    static std::default_random_engine generator{ rd() };
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{ 'a', 'z' };

    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    std::string s(string_length, ' ');

    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < size; n++)
    {
        for (std::size_t m = 0; m < string_length; ++m)
        {
            s[m] = static_cast<char>(distribution(generator));
        }

        strings.emplace_back(s);
    }

    return strings;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings = generate_strings(1000000, 3);
    //std::vector<std::string> strings{ "a","b","a","a","c","d","a" };

    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;
    std::vector<int> output;

    // speed optimization, allocate enough room for answer
    // so output doesn't have to reallocate when growing.
    output.reserve(strings.size());

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    int id = 0;
    for (const auto& string : strings)
    {
        if (map.find(string) == map.end())
        {
            output.push_back(id);
            map.insert({ string, id });
            id++;
        }
        else
        {
            output.push_back(map.at(string));
        }
    }

    auto duration = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
    auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration).count();

    auto seconds = static_cast<double>(nanoseconds) / 1.0e9;

    /*
    for (const auto& value : output)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this awesome solution! On my machine it's even faster (0.2s), and its strings of length ~25 there! Must say that same strings are repeated very often, though!

Comment: You may thank the builders of the standard library :) But happy it works for you

Answer (score 3):

If you need just the keys, why don't you use just a vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> s {"a","b","a","a","c","d","a"};
    std::vector<int> out(s.size());
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), out.begin(),[](auto& x)
    {
        return x[0] - 'a';
    });
    for(auto& i : out) std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgAcpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BXLaY9o4CdQ0ERRHRsXoK9Y3NOW0jvf0lZRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmm25OI8SYrEfYJhoAgls7e5iHx2ehwFc392bbDLteByObgAbtUiMRPncHn8ni83GJgCRCAgWJD7lC7qECPsWExQhB5l8TAB2Kx3fYU/YjdAgECghwkIHU2lvIxXKmHUnmMxMbmkblRPnc3lmALCoWi0yi/mi9ASnnckkAESOZNulKpBBpdLBjOOWPZywIEAUADo0gAvTAEwmbNUa5kgAjEQwKfjEFgm00xYD4xZU02uAmkfZG72YX0MYMmACsVhjSogTC8RHMADZ9qpCeTKST7RrKecCCsGJnYxYNLGlfsALT7MAcJgN1VfDXK235inupMp1Dp/Z4fYgUMp%2Baa7VoFNwoED6fHQ6ihdmFs5imOyfYoEzx2uWgr9WFzDF4ilyt2onEpUcRa0Tgx3h%2BDhaUioThuazWKnLVbPLY8UgEJo16LAA1iAmybKaEHQTBsFpvonCSA%2BQEvpwvAKCAGgAUBixwLASBoCwSR0LE5CUIRxH0HEwBcLRfB0AQsQYRAUQoVEoQNAAnpw/6EWwggAPIMLQ3FPrwWC4kY4hiaQ%2BDnDUoIYTJmCqNUKbrM%2BWIdChtB4FELrEJxHhYChzp4CwPHXnwBjAAoABqeCYAA7gJSSMJZMiCCIYjsFInnyEoagobobQGEYKAfpY%2Bh6RhkCLKgSRdAwSnoR0YIZC4DDuJ4LR6MEoQDKUQxtCkaRJeMrR5GVGQzIM5TtJ0tSjE0OUTA16XdM1tVFfVUxjK1lV9X0BWzMViwKN%2Bax6M6mDrDwN53shMmvhwqjxGmNZppI%2BzAMgyD7LRppcPsEDvpY1ghrghAkAumxtPsHhESRxC3Vw8y8IBYnzKB4GQbB/3QfBt4cEhpCPs%2BK3oZh2FfaQeGICARpJCmZEQBRz15fg4J6PwXmiOIfm4wFKjqDJM1zbwTkukklkLRw95gyhK0CSmyPYqgVCZutm3bbt%2B2Hcdp2oE9VGve9MNaN9pBgRBUEA/9CEg0tENobY0OfZLdNmMrvCQxLwGkKCxBpM4khAA%3D)